# I want to split an activity into several classes. is it possible?

Tags: android

I'm finishing an application, the thing is that I have a couple of layouts and all the code concentrated in an Activity.
I have 5000 lines of codes and when I have to fix something is a pain in the ass to find what im looking for.

as im really new in Android development, I can't find a way to split the code into several classes.
is there a simply way of split one layout with one activity?
its really annoying to declare each layout with his corresponding activity in the manifest.

thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: If you have 5000 lines of code in one class then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Could you further explain what you mean by declaring each layout? If by "layout" you mean xml layout, you shouldn't need to do that. A snippet from your android manifest would help

Comment: it should be possible to identify new objects in your code, and move that logic in new classes and new methods. Though, providing help would not be possible until you expose your architecture, or the whole code.

Comment: Yes i know i was doing it wrong. That's why i'm asking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you have multiple layouts for a single Activity? You could check out the [Fragments API](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and divide up the Activity into easily manageable Fragments. As for the 5,000 lines of code, try to divide that up into separate classes with static access or is there a way you could use data objects? You really shouldn't have 5,000 lines of code in ONE class, divide that up into separate classes.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it is not Android. But OOP (Object Oriented Programming) concept.

Of course you can split function in one Activity into several classes. For example, if you have AsyncTask you could make it outside an Activity, if you have Adapter that reads from DB you could also make it outside an Activity. Just call to those classes when needed. And any other general functions you could also make it outside an Activity perhaps in Utility class or something.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the Android way is to use activities to hold your layouts; that is what they are intended to be used for.  It would be a good idea to make your program as object oriented as possible... Here's why..

1. Java is an object oriented programming language.
2. Help make your code easier for you to understand, follow, and make changes to.
3. To make your code easy for OTHERS to follow.
4. Ensure cohesiveness in your application.

So it would be a good idea to make your application as functionally cohesive as possible.  It will save you much trouble in the future.